# How to find closed form formula for sequences defined by $a_n = ra_{n-1} + d$

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, closed-form

I'm looking for a formula to find the closed form for sequences defined with the form: 
$$a_n = ra_{n-1} + d$$
I know I can do pattern recognition to find a closed form. For example if given the sequence:
$$a_n = 2a_{n-1} + 3, a_1 = 1$$
I could write out the terms:
\begin{align*}
a_1 &= 1  & &= 4 - 3  & = 2^2 - 3 \\
a_2 &= 5  & &= 8 - 3  & = 2^3 - 3 \\
a_3 &= 13 & &= 16 - 3  & = 2^4 - 3 \\
a_4 &= 29 & &= 32 - 3  & = 2^5 - 3 \\
a_5 &= 61 & &= 64 - 3 & = 2^6 - 3
\end{align*}
Which would suggest the closed form: $a_n = 2^{n+1} - 3$

However such a pattern is not always immediately obvious or apparent.

Is there anything like the nice arithmetic $a_n = a_1 + (n - 1)d$ or geometric $a_n = a_1r^{n-1}$ formulas that I could use?

At first I thought this was an [Arithmetico-geometric sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico-geometric_sequence), but I don't believe that is quite what this is. That page led me to [Linear difference equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_difference_equation) which doesn't include anything about finding a closed form.

Comment: This is a geometric series.

Comment: Hint: Consider the quantity $a_n-a_{n-1}$, using two cases of the recurrence relation...

Comment: In the first link you gave, the answer was given in the [first section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico-geometric_sequence#Sequence.2C_nth_term)...

Comment: Hint: To solve the recursion $a\to ra+d$, **find the fixed point** (if any), that is, $a^*$ such that $a^*=ra^*+d$ and **consider the centered quantity** $\bar a_n=a_n-a^*$. In your case, $a^*=d/(1-r)$ and the recursion becomes $\bar a\to r\bar a$ hence $\bar a_n=r^n\bar a_0$, which is equivalent to $a_n=a^*+r^n(a_0-a^*)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that

$$\begin{align}a_n&=ra_{n-1}+d\\&=r(ra_{n-2}+d)+d=r^2a_{n-2}+d+dr\\&=r^2(ra_{n-3}+d)+d+dr=r^3a_{n-3}+d+dr+dr^2\\&=r^3(ra_{n-4}+d)+d+dr+dr^2=r^4a_{n-4}+d+dr+dr^2+dr^3\\&\qquad\vdots\\&=r^{n-1}a_1+d(1+r+r^2+r^3+\dots+r^{n-2})=r^{n-1}a_1+d\frac{1-r^{n-1}}{1-r}\end{align}$$

> $$a_n=r^{n-1}a_1+d\frac{1-r^{n-1}}{1-r}$$

Now prove this is true by induction.

---

For your example, we would then have:

$$a_n=2^{n-1}-3(1-2^{n-1})=2^{n+1}-3$$

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I wanted. I noticed in the comment above that you said the answer was given in the wiki page for the arithmetico-geometric sequence. I don't quite see how this sequence can be formed by multiplying the terms of an arithmetic and geometric sequence. This solution also seems very different from the one on the wiki page.

Comment: I would imagine there are many different ways to go about this, but I agree, I like this solution.

Answer (score 0):

1) Solving the homogeneous difference equation $a_n=ra_{n-1}$ gives $a_n=cr^n$.

2) A particular solution of the nonhomogeneous  difference equation $a_n=ra_{n-1}+d$ is given by $a_n=k$, $\;\;\;$where $k=rk+d$ so $\;k=\frac{d}{1-r}$.

The general soluton of the nonhomogeneous equation is given by adding these two solutions to get

$\;\;\displaystyle a_n=cr^n+\frac{d}{1-r},\;\;$ and $a_2=cr^2+\frac{d}{1-r}=ra_1+d\implies c=\frac{1}{r}\left(a_1-\frac{d}{1-r}\right)$, so

$\;\;\displaystyle a_n=\frac{1}{r}\left(a_1-\frac{d}{1-r}\right)r^n+\frac{d}{1-r}=a_1r^{n-1}+\frac{d}{1-r}\left(1-r^{n-1}\right)$